# Renaming files based on mime type

Tags: bash, media, mime-types

I have a folder full of files without an extension that are either JPG or MP4.  I'm trying to figure out how to use *file* to determine the mime type and then add the appropriate extension.

I need to do this in Bash.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Not a bad question, try to [improve it](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines.

```sh
for file in *; do
  if [[ $(file "$file") =~ ": JPEG" ]]; then
    mv "$file" "$file".jpg
  elif [[ $(file "$file") =~ ": ISO Media, MP4" ]]; then
    mv "$file" "$file".mp4
  fi;
done;
```

Comment: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.